# Is there any way I can list the folders and files and download from Dropbox through my Android App but without having Dropbox installed on the device?

Tags: android, download, dropbox

I need to list all the files and folders of Dropbox account and download them. Actually i am able to do this but only when i have Dropbox app installed in my device and if app is not installed it is redirecting me to the page which request to install app.Please suggest a way in which app is not required.Currently I am using DROPBOX Chooser SDK in my app.

Comment: IT'S ANNOYING TO OTHER USERS WHEN YOU TYPE IN ALL CAPITAL LETTERS PLEASE DON'T DO THIS

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to understand what we expect from questions and answers posted on this site. We are different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Android Core SDK will let you do this: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android.